# Customizing Django Admin Site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am building an application using [Django JET](http://jet.geex-arts.com/) which is essentially a skin on the Django Admin site. I need to enable batch updates for a field in a related model. So ultimately my question is how can I do so?

To illustrate, I have two models:

```
from django.db import models


class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Bar(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'BEST'),
        ('B', 'GOOD'),
        ('C', 'WORST'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I also have an admin for the parent model and an inline for the related model:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from admin_example import models


class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.Bar


@admin.register(models.Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BarInline,)
```

I want to be able to batch update `quality` for all `Bar` instances related to the current `Foo` instance. The user still must be able to edit `quality` for each `Bar` individually as well. My idea is to add a `<select>` dropdown box to the `BarInline`. I've looked into writing my own template for `BarInline`. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to `bulk_update` all the instances of `bar`, related to a particular instance of `foo` with the same value of `quality`.

For this case, the better approach would be to move the `quality` attribute to `Foo` model. So that, each instance of `bar` for a particular instance of `foo` can access the same value of `quality`.

Updating each instance of `bar` with same value of `quality` is too much repeated work if done via the admin.

Comment: how do you answer on the main question, `customize django admin site`?

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, this does not meet the requirements laid out in my original question. Each `Bar` instance must have its own `quality` that can be edited independently from each other. I am implementing a UI feature which allows the user to batch edit the `quality` of all `Bar` instances for a given `Foo`. Later, the user can still edit individual `Bar` instances. My question is about customizing the django admin site to allow this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to add a UI feature, you may want to take a look to the [`template` attribute for an `InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.template)

```
class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.Bar
    template = '/path/to/your/template.html'
```

This template is responsible for rendering all the set of individual `Bar` objects that will be displayed. You may want to take a look at the default [template for `StackedInline`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html)